# Display data in a popup window in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to show data in a popup window. popup window will be show by clicking on an image. but data doesn't show.

javascript codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.popup').click(function () {
            $('.box').show("slow");
            $('.close').show("slow");
        })
        $('.close').click(function () {
            $('.box').hide("slow");
        })
    })
</script>
```

by click on image1 popup window show and by click on image 11 an image sould be show in popup window but doesn't work.

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" CssClass="popup"  />
<div class="box">
    <div class="close">
        ×
    </div>
    <center>

    <asp:Image ID="Image11" runat="server" CssClass=bigpic />
    </center>
</div>
```

the image show but fade quickly!

Comment: what data - where they are? what library do you use ?

Comment: you need to add `CssClass="popup"` to Image11

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery UI library to display a popup, here's an example:

**Javascript:**

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.popup').click(function () {
            $(".box").dialog({
                title: "jQuery Dialog Popup",
                buttons: {
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                },
                modal: true
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" CssClass="popup" ImageUrl="~/Images/img1.jpg" />
<div class="box">
    <asp:Image ID="Image11" runat="server" CssClass="bigpic" />
</div>
```

Comment: Copy and paste the code EXACTLY the way it is in my example.You need to add a script reference to jQuery and then under it a reference to jQuery UI and jQuery UI css